# BabylonJS Tab freezing when calling new Babylon.Engine in a fresh project

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I wanted to rewrite a project of mine in babylon js so i created a new directory added a html file and added the script tags for babylon etc...

Everything works fine till i create the engine.

If i uncomment this line:

```
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
```

everything works. But with this line the tab freezes. It probably goes into a endless loop, but i didn't change anything in the babylonjs file. The Canvas is not undefined and i also checked if other browsers worked but they freeze as well.

It previously worked but one day i wanted to work on it and it doesnt even load the website.

Im using the latest version of babylon.

Btw: The Babylon Sandbox doesnt load for me too. So it may be a problem with my pc, since the sanbox works for others?

Edit: After clearing the cache it works in firefox, but chrome still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify if anyone got this problem too. This had nothing to do with babylonjs. After a few days it just went away. Probably had something to do with my pc or browser.